# Flash game works on some computers but not on others

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs3

I have a cvery strange problem and just cannot work it out and was wondering if anyone on here knows the solution.

The problem i am facing is as follows.

we have a flash game and it works on the computers in the office (flash player 10 and flash player 9.0.159)

however when we try to run it on one of our laptops it fails and just does not load the content we are trying to load (however the same version works on other computers). the version on the laptop is flash player 9.0.159

This is a major problem as some clients we have got have experienced the same thing also. But i am totally stumped at what it can be has anyone got any ideas?

Cheers
Mark

Comment: please provide more info — this could be anything, from security violation, bugged code, typo in resource location to no internet connection at all. you *have* to know what’s going on behind the scenes (is the resource even requested? if not, why? is the request code executed? if resource is returned, if the contents is ok? etc...)

Comment: is it being run from a website or standalone?

Comment: it does it on the web version and standalone. There a no firewall restrictions set that are different from any other computer. There is an internet connection the resources does not load but it needs to load (it loads on other machines just not this one) there is no security violation errors that come up and i put code in to prevent security violations being an issue

Comment: And the laptop you test on have the debug player installed? - If not try and install it and see if you get any error´s.

Comment: yeah it has but it has no errors that show.

Answer (score 2):

Just to let everyone know. i worked out that the problem was because the xml file i was reading was to large (20 thousand lines) after splitting the loading up it works fine.

so before the 15 second time limit of a script execution in flash was cutting in before the file was read on slower pc's

Thanks for all the help people gave.
Regards
Mark

Comment: That's really interesting! Thanks for getting back to us.

Answer (score 0):

firewall, network issue? maybe your office has higher access to some required resource than the clients/remote users get? Provide details.

Comment: it does it on the web version and standalone. There a no firewall restrictions set that are different from any other computer. There is an internet connection the resources does not load but it needs to load (it loads on other machines just not this one) there is no security violation errors that come up and i put code in to prevent security violations being an issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a big render or process within a single frame which could time out?

Comment: na no massive processing or nothing that is what i cannot understand